# Prove the inequality $\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy} \geq \frac{3}{1+\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}}$ when $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have to prove the inequality
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy} \geq \frac{3}{1+\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}}
$$
when $x^2+y^2=1$, using **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality**.

The RHS is equal to $\frac{12}{5+2xy}$.
I can prove, using C-S, that the RHS is $\geq \frac{9}{4+xy}$ or  $\geq \frac{12}{5+4xy}$ but I can't go further.

---

I can prove the inequality only using A.M.-G.M. inequality proving that $xy\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and simplifying the expression all together, but this is not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Various solutions (not using CS) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970971.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $xy\geq0$ by C-S $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}=\frac{3}{2+x^2y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}=$$
$$=\frac{4}{\frac{4(2+x^2y^2)}{3}}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\geq\frac{(2+1)^2}{\frac{4(2+x^2y^2)}{3}+1+xy}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{9}{\frac{4(2+x^2y^2)}{3}+1+xy}\geq\frac{12}{5+2xy}$$ or
$$(1-2xy)(1+8xy)\geq0,$$ which is true by C-S again:
$$2=(x^2+y^2)(1^2+1^2)\geq(x+y)^2=1+2xy,$$ which gives $1-2xy\geq0.$

For $xy\leq0$ by C-S again we obtain
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{1+xy}=\frac{1}{\frac{2+x^2y^2}{3}}+\frac{1}{1+xy}\geq\frac{4}{\frac{2+x^2y^2}{3}+1+xy}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{4}{\frac{2+x^2y^2}{3}+1+xy}\geq\frac{12}{5+2xy}$$ or
$$x^2y^2+xy-2\leq0$$ or
$$(1-xy)(2+xy)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Thanks. I like very much the last step! In your opinion is it possible to prove the inequality without rearranging the LHS and RHS together?

Comment: I think, we can't because $-\frac{12}{5+2xy}$ is negative.

Comment: Could you explain the first inequality further? I don't understand how to deduce it from the Cauchy-Schwartz. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @awllower I used the following C-S. For positives $c$ and $d$ we have $\frac{a^2}{c}+\frac{b^2}{d}\geq\frac{(a+b)^2}{c+d}.$ It's just $(c+d)\left(\frac{a^2}{c}+\frac{b^2}{d}\right)\geq(a+b)^2.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ok thanks! But in this case is not necessary the first step with C-S, because rearranging we arrive at $(2x-1)(5x^2+3x+1)\leq 0$ which is true...Any way thanks!

Comment: @Alex Yes, of course! It's exactly the cause why I don't understand, why we need to use C-S here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I found it as an exercise on a chapter on C-S. I don't know! Thaks:)

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand the inequality $(1-2xy)(1+8xy)\geq0:$ if $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}$ then the LHS is $<0$.

Comment: @awllower You are right! My proof works for non-negative variables. I see a way, how we can fix it, but today I am very very busy. I'll fix it later. Thank you!